# Input nearby rails model info from geocoder into gmaps4rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I'm using the newer gmaps4rails and I can't seem to figure out how to make my nearby stores be located in gmaps4rails. In the show page I have my nearby stores code.

I placed information on the .js code where I believe the rails code should be but it's not working correctly. I've tried `<%= storeuser.latitude %>` and `<%= storeuser.longitude %>`, but those don't work. I would rather it map all of my stores and allow me to focus on just nearbys within a specific radius on gmaps.

My code is below:

**Show page**:

```
<body onload = 'getLocation()'>

    <div class = 'map'>
      <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='sidebar_container'>
    </div>

    <div class= "test"></div>
    <h3>Nearby locations</h3>
    <ul id="nearby_locations">
        <% @nearby_stores.each do |storeuser| %>
        <li><%= link_to storeuser.storename, profile_path(storeuser) %>(<%= storeuser.distance.round(2) %> miles) </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**Application.js**:

```
var x = document.getElementById("map");
        function getLocation()
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            else{x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
        }
        function showPosition(position)
        {
            function createSidebarLi(json){
              return ("<li><a>" + json.name + "</a></li>");
            };

            function bindLiToMarker($li, marker){
              $li.on('click', function(){
                handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
                marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
                marker.panTo();
                google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
              })
            };

            function createSidebar(json_array){
              _.each(json_array, function(json){
                var $li = $( createSidebarLi(json) );
                $li.appendTo('#sidebar_container');
                bindLiToMarker($li, json.marker);
              });
            };

            handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
            handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
                var json_array = [
                    {
                        "lat": position.coords.latitude,
                        "lng": position.coords.longitude,
                        "name": 'You!',
                        "picture": {
                            "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                            "width":  36,
                            "height": 36
                        },
                        "infowindow": "You!"
                    },
                    {
                        "lat": Do I put rails code here and how should it look?,
                        "lng": "",
                        "name": 'Store!',
                        "picture": {
                            "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                            "width":  36,
                            "height": 36
                        },
                        "infowindow": "You!"
                    }
                ];

                var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);

                _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
                    json.marker = markers[index];
                });
                createSidebar(json_array);
                handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                handler.fitMapToBounds();
            });
            var lat = position.coords.latitude
            var lon = position.coords.longitude
            var parsed_data = {location: {lat: lat, lon: lon}}
            if (!window.location.search) {
                window.location = ('/findme?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon);    
            }

        }
```

**locations controller for show page**:

```
def show2
    @nearby_stores = (params[:lat].present? && params[:lon].present?) ? Storeuser.near([params[:lat], params[:lon]], 50) : []
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

**Storeuser model**:

```
class Storeuser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "200x200", :semismall => "250x250", :medium => "300x300>", :large => "400x400", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


  def full_address
    [address, city, state, zipcode].compact.join(', ')
  end

  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode



end
```

***Migration Table(though I'm not sure how this helps)**:

```
class DeviseCreateStoreusers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:storeusers) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0, :null => false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      t.string :username
      t.string :ownerfirstname
      t.string :ownerlastname
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zipcode
      t.string :storename

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :storeusers, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :storeusers, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :storeusers, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :storeusers, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
  end
end
```

now I am getting "undefined local variable or method `gon' for #" I placed

**Location Controller**:
    @nearby_stores = (params[:lat].present? && params[:lon].present?) ? Storeuser.near([params[:lat], params[:lon]], 50) : []
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
        end
        gon.nearby_stores_lat = @nearby_stores.latitude
        gon.nearby_stores_lon = @nearby_stores.longitude
        gon.nearby_stores_name = @nearby_stores.truckname

**updated application.js**

```
var x = document.getElementById("map");
        function getLocation()
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            else{x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
        }
        function showPosition(position)
        {
            function createSidebarLi(json){
              return ("<li><a>" + json.name + "</a></li>");
            };

            function bindLiToMarker($li, marker){
              $li.on('click', function(){
                handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
                marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
                marker.panTo();
                google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
              })
            };

            function createSidebar(json_array){
              _.each(json_array, function(json){
                var $li = $( createSidebarLi(json) );
                $li.appendTo('#sidebar_container');
                bindLiToMarker($li, json.marker);
              });
            };

            handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
            handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
                var json_array = [
                    {
                        "lat": position.coords.latitude,
                        "lng": position.coords.longitude,
                        "name": 'You!',
                        "picture": {
                            "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                            "width":  36,
                            "height": 36
                        },
                        "infowindow": "You!"
                    },
                    {
                        "lat": gon.nearby_trucks_lat,
                        "lng": gon.nearby_trucks_lon,
                        "name": gon.nearby_trucks_name,
                        "picture": {
                            "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                            "width":  36,
                            "height": 36
                        },
                        "infowindow": gon.nearby_trucks_name
                    }
                ];

                var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);

                _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
                    json.marker = markers[index];
                });
                createSidebar(json_array);
                handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                handler.fitMapToBounds();
            });
            var lat = position.coords.latitude
            var lon = position.coords.longitude
            var parsed_data = {location: {lat: lat, lon: lon}}
            if (!window.location.search) {
                window.location = ('/findme?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon);    
            }

        }
```

Comment: What does the model and migration look like for @nearby_stores?

Comment: hint: store the expected coordinates with gon

Comment: Is gon a gem? I've never used. it. I'm fairly new to rails, but I will google it. I will update the model.

Comment: now I am getting "undefined local variable or method `gon' for #<LocationsController:0x00000105542738>"

Comment: Updated at the bottom, but I'm not sure I did it correctly. I did everything that the gem stated, but it doesn't work. Also i did use the <%= include_gon %> at the top of my application page